# Iterate through SQL select query to get more related data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I would like to generate an excel report based on a SQL stored procedure.

Therefore i have to 'fill' few columns on this report. Some are related to (let's say) the Order table, others are related to the Product table and so on.

On the excel report i need to see the columns: Order no, Order value, Product 1 name, Product 2 name, Product 1 value, Product 2 value (there are max 2 products on each order).

The Product table is linked to the Order table.

[image: report example]

I know this kind of listing it's a bit confusing, but that is what i wanna get.

Atm i have written the sequence:

```
SELECT 
order.OrderNo,
order.OrderValue,
product.Name,
product.Value

From ORDER AS order
lEFT outer join PRODUCT as product on order.OrderId = product.OrderId
```

The query works but i only get data for the first product in each order. Is there a way to select data from all products specific to each order?

Comment: You can use array_agg function maybe

Comment: Have you tried using a `PIVOT`?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different features.)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.) Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT op.OrderNo, op.OrderValue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Name END) as Name_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Value END) as Value_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN Name END) as Name_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN Value END) as Value_2
FROM (SELECT o.OrderNo, o.OrderValue, p.Name, p.Value,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.OrderNo ORDER BY p.Value DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ORDER o LEFT JOIN
           PRODUCT p
           ON o.OrderId = p.OrderId
     ) op
GROUP BY op.OrderNo, op.OrderValue;
```

Comment: This is nice, especially as you don't need to know what specific values might appear in `Product.Name`, but just the maximum distinct values there will be.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it, you can use a `PIVOT` for this, for example:

```
declare @order table(
    OrderId int,
    OrderNo varchar(10),
    OrderValue decimal(10,2)
)

declare @product table(
    OrderId int,
    [Name] varchar(20),
    [Value] decimal(10,2)
)

insert into @order values
(1,'ORD001',436.45),
(2,'ORD002',964.33),
(3,'ORD003',1265.98)

insert into @product values
(1,'Widget',195.45),
(1,'Doohickey',241.00),
(2,'Widget',195.45),
(2,'Thingy',397.99),
(2,'Doofer',370.89),
(3,'Widget',195.45),
(3,'Thingy',397.99),
(3,'Foobar',415.78),
(3,'Whatchamacallit',256.76)

select
    OrderNo,
    OrderValue,
    [Widget],
    [Doohickey],
    [Thingy],
    [Doofer],
    [Foobar],
    [Whatchamacallit]
from
(
    select
        o.OrderNo,
        o.OrderValue,
        p.[Name],
        p.[Value]
    from @order o
    left join @product p on o.OrderId = p.OrderId
) SourceTable
pivot
(
    sum([Value])
    for [Name] in ([Widget], [Doohickey], [Thingy], [Doofer], [Foobar], [Whatchamacallit])
) as PivotTable
```

gives you this result:

[image: Results]

However, this does require you to know all the distinct values of `Product.Name` which could appear and to include them in your query. The upside is you can perform further aggregation on the resultant values, per Product.